Adding an item into the card by clicking on custom button in Shopify
I would like to have a custom button in Shopify, that would add certain item to the shopping card based on a fixed product ID.
I did try to add this code to custom HTML on a custom page in the page editor:
page editor
<button id="custom-add-to-cart" data-product-id="11564478366041">Add to Cart</button>

And this javascript code to a new asset file named custom.js:
document.getElementById('custom-add-to-cart').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var productId = this.getAttribute('data-product-id');
    addToCart(productId, 1); // 1 indicates the quantity

    function addToCart(productId, quantity) {
        fetch('/cart/add.js', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: productId,
                quantity: quantity
            })
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Product added to cart:', data);
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
        });
    }
});

And this to the theme.liquid:


<script src="{{ 'custom.js' | asset_url }}"></script>



But the code does not work.

You need to check the variant Id instead of the product id.

As said you should be sure to pass the variant id and not the product id.
About your code: no need to create a function inside a event listener because it won't be accessible outside of that event listener.
You could remove the addToCart function entirely and put the fetch code directly inside the event listener function or if you need to call addToCart from elsewhere in your code, you should define it outside of the event listener function.
You can also achieve this without JS by using cart permalinks provided by Shopify
https://my-shop-name.myshopify.com/cart/variant_id:quantity

See doc: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/details/cart-permalink#examples-of-cart-permalinks
Just know that such a link will directs customers to the checkout or to the cart page if you add the parameter ?storefront=true
